# Twitter User Time Line Feed using date parameter

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am working on sentiment analysis for which I need twitter feed. I have implemented the php code to get the json feed and parse it as I wanted. the problem is I could not find a way to get json feed as per the date specified.

```
$query = array(  
    'screen_name' => 'twitterapi',
    'count' => '5'
);
```

Using the above syntax I have to specify the number of tweets but my requirement is to get the feed for specific date. Is it possible to pass date parameter instead of count.
currently I am using $path = '/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';

I have also implemented the mechanism to manually filter the date but for that I have to provide very large count for older dates that unnecessarily slows down the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.

Firstly, [read the documentation for the API call](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) you're making.  You can't pass a date - but you can request up to 200 Tweets and, if that isn't enough, page through up to 3,200 of their most recent tweets.

Secondly, [read the documentation for Searching Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets), you can use the `until` parameter to search for older Tweets.  Twitter's search API only goes back ~7 days.  As they say:

> Please note that Twitter’s search service and, by extension, the Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I need tweets of specific date say for example 30th Aug 2015, the accounts under consideration are very active accounts and tweet very frequently, it is therefore not possible for me to assume a count and then filter thousands of tweets. This will slow down the whole thing. The other option of max 7 days wont work for me.

Comment: No, you can't do that.  Sorry.